# ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

I'm using `squeel` and I'm getting a `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain` returned from a query rather than an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`.

Query:

```
game.golfers.where{competitors.swing_golfer IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE}
```

Query that returns `AssociationRelation`

```
game.golfers.where{"competitors.swing_golfer IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE"}
```

Notice the quotes change the return type.

Models

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitors
  has_many :golfers, through: :competitors
end

class Golfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitors
  has_many :games, through: :competitors
end
```

Any idea what this `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain` is and how I can use it or avoid it?

- ruby 2.0.0
- rails 4.0
- squeel 1.1.1

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this article:

http://erniemiller.org/2013/10/07/activerecord-where-not-sane-true/

where Ernie says "Its sole purpose is to exist to expose a not method,.."

Basically it was designed so that you could modify the original condition with a call to .not(...) without having to duplicate it.